# Adding JPanel on top of PApplet

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, processing

I've been working with the [Unfolding Maps](http://unfoldingmaps.org/) library, and this library uses a PApplet to display the map. My issue is that I am trying to layer a JPanel (Swing component) on top of a PApplet. I am able to layer the JPanel on top of another JPanel, but when I try to layer the JPanel on top of the PApplet, the PApplet is no longer displayed. I read through the [PApplet documentation](http://processing.org/reference/javadoc/core/processing/core/PApplet.html), and it does mention issues that arise when drawing Swing components on top of a PApplet, but I have not been able to find a resolution to this issue.

Is there a way I can layer a transparent JPanel on top of a PApplet and still maintain the functionality of the PApplet and the JPanel?

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method is to do the reverse; add the `PApplet` to the `JPanel`.  Then add your decorations either to the `JPanel` surrounding the `PApplet` or override the `draw()` method of the `PApplet` to add your overlay.

```
myJPanel.add(myPApplet);
myPApplet.init();
```

Comment: That is essentially what I have at the moment, but the issue occurs when I try to layer the panel on top of the `PApplet`, and say add a button in the `JPanel`. (The layering is done by using a `JLayeredPane`.)